# "Load more comments" button -> How to indicate that there are no more entries in database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I am writing a comment system and I only display a certain number of comments on initial load of the page.

There is a "Load more comments" button that loads more comments from the database and appends it via ajax(jquery).

They are either ordered by timestamp or another column.

How can I detect whether the last comment was loaded during the method that is called by the "Load more comments" button?

I have a table where the total amount of comments is saved, should I just get that number and compare the loaded comments with the total comment count? Or is there a simple mysqli method that does the job?

Thank you

Comment: just check if last result is empty

Comment: I need the information in advance. I don't want the user to get the information that there are no more comments after clicking the button. Actually I want to hide it when there are no more entries.

Comment: When loading more comments from the sql table, what is the limit of the number of comments you load at once?

Comment: add a conditional to count the comments and display the button if greater than req amount

Comment: make your server responses more intelligent

Comment: @ChukwuemekaOnyenezido I think I will display about 15 and then add 15. I already had the idea to load 16 from the database and check if I got the additional one but then the database is loading this additional comment every time the user displays comments or loads more.

Comment: On the back end, after loading 15 on request from the front end, try to load one more comment. If you can load this, set a boolean more_comments_left to true, if you cannot load this extra comment set the boolean more_comments_left to false. Then send this boolean and the 15 comments in response to the front end.

Comment: @ChukwuemekaOnyenezido I think I will do this but I will not waste the additional comment but store it and use it if the user loads more comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
 The solution of your problem is you need to apply condition that, 
 if result is more than one or not let me show you
 This is just example not pure code.........

 // result array from database 

 $fetchRes = mysql_fetch_result("mysql query result with offset and limit");
 $totalRes = (int)count($fetchRes);
 if( isset($totalRes) && $totalRes > 0 ){
   echo "your comments";
 }else{
   echo "No more comments";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

On initial loading of the comments the script loads n+1 comments from the database - n is the number of comments to be displayed.

If comment nr. n+1 can be loaded, it is not only an indicator of more available comments but it is also stored in a variable on the local machine - it is not displayed yet.

When the user loads more comments, it will start on comment nr. n+2 and load n from the database so it has n+1 comments again whereas the last comment -again- is not displayed but is an indicator for more available comments.

Comparing to aforementioned answers this solution will only load one additional comment on initial display of comments (n+1). After initialization it will only load n more from the database as the offset of 1 comment that was produced on first comment loading has a consecutive effect.

So after initialization I can save the load of 1 entry per additional comment loading with this method.